# Cut sink out of molded vanity top

Tags: sink, cutting, vanity, sinkhole

Is it possible to cut the sink out a molded vanity top? We would like to put in a table top style sink, but to do so we need a counter top with a hole for the sink. Trying to save money and use the counter top we already have.

Comment: Is this molded steel top ?  A photo always helps

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Diamond blade on a grinder would probably work. [Edit] your question and add a pic or 2 (using the "sun & mountains" button so we can get some idea what your vanity looks like.

Comment: Most materials can be cut given appropriate tools.   unless your top is tempered glass or something even more exotic it can probably be cut.

Comment: It *sounds* like the OP wants to convert a (below counter) cultured marble sink/counter to a (above counter) vessel type, but the question is so ill-written I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Almost always, **yes**, (assuming the hole left will be covered by the new sink) but what tooling you need depends what the sink/counter is made from - Something like Corian® (generically, solid surface countertop material) is a lot easier to cut (being just thick plastic) than a stone-like or porcelain-like material - those can be cut but will require diamond tooling and water cooling, usually.

You *might be better off* looking for a new (or new-to-you - visit your Habitat ReStore, if there's one in range, or similar building materials recycler if that's not applicable to your area) countertop and selling your old top and sink to someone else.